# How can I alter a methods local variables with a callback?

Tags: javascript, ruby

```
var hello = function(callback) {
    var greet = "hello world";
    var name = "doug";
    callback();
    console.log(greet, name)
}

hello(function() {
    greet = "こにちわ";
    name = "だぐ";
    console.log(greet, name)

})
こにちわ だぐ
hello world doug
```

Is it possible to override the local variable outside of the closure and run the rest of the function in that scope? So, I want an output of:

```
こにちわ だぐ
こにちわ だぐ
```

I realise the scope in the callback is just shadowing the local variables in the outer scope, but is there a way to directly access the outer scope and alter the variables there?

Bonus, is this possible in Ruby?

**Edit:** 
I was able to do it this way, is there a better way?:

```
var hello = function(callback) {
    this.greet = "hello world";
    this.name = "doug";
    callback.call(this);
    console.log(greet, name)
}

hello(function() {
    this.greet = "こにちわ";
    this.name = "だぐ";
    console.log(this.greet, this.name)

})
```

Comment: you can use instance variables in ruby to achieve same

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same in Ruby with instance variables, as shown below:

```
def hello(&block)
  @a = "Foo"
  @greet = "Hello"
  block.call
  puts "#{@greet}, #{@a}"
  end

 hello do
   @a = "Bar"
   @greet = "Hi"
  puts "#{@greet}, #{@a}"
 end

# => Hi, Bar
# => Hi, Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript:

`this.var` as fair I remember is not local variable. As my knowledge about Javascript is limited, I would say that version with `this.var` is good.
Depending on your needs, I would suggest just pass a argument(s), for example `var hello = function(var1)`. You can use some sort of hash:

```
var h = new Object()
h['greet'] = 'Hello'
```

### Ruby:

As [bjhaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669123/2597260) said, you can use instance variables (`@a="new value"` somewhere in your code).

You can use global variables (`$var`). Without new class/object, global and instance variables are very similar: whole program can change it.
If you are creating new class/object, I suggest to stick with instance variables because only class/object can change it (of course without metaprogramming like `some_object.instance_variable_set :@a, '34'`).

I guess you will use instance variables in most cases, however I should write other ways as your needs may vary.

> How can I alter a methods local variables with a callback?

If you really need local variables:

```
def meth1 &block # & - change block to the lambda
  a = 42
  b = 33
  block.call binding # "send" local scope (variables like `a`, `b`) to the block
  puts a,b
end

# `bin` is what you send in the `meth1` method; 
`eval` may change variables etc
meth1 {|bin| bin.eval 'a="str"'; bin.eval 'b=:FF' }
```

You may use *implicit return from the block* (you cannot use `return` with blocks of type `proc`; and block send to the method is transformed to the `proc` type block)

```
def meth2 &block
  a = 1
  b = 2
  a, b = block.call # returns array (in this case); equivalent: `arr=block.call; a=arr[0]; b=arr[1]`
  puts a,b
end

meth2 {[2,3]}
```

Of course can use the fact that few variables can *point* to a one object, for example string. If you modify that string, every variable that point to that string will see the change. This is called modifying in place, as fair I remember.

```
def meth3 &block
  a = "string a"
  b = "something b"
  block.call a, b
  puts a, b
end


meth3 do |a,b|
  a.gsub! 's', '*'
  b.gsub! 'b', '^'
end
```

However, this method is limited. You can modify in place string, array, hash but you cannot modify symbols or numbers. Method that modify in place may have `!` (bang) at the end of its name but it is no a rule.

#### Notes:

This methods are made simple to show how to do something. I should note that:
`eval` may run almost any code. It is dangerous (and slow) so use it with cautions. You should check string that you pass to the `eval`

Blocks: if you don't send block (for example just call `meth3`) it will raise an error. You may want to check if there is a block - [method `block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F).
You may check what block returns (in cases similar to `meth2`). You may change variables to the default value when block doesn't return anything *good*.

Modyfying in place: I consider it to be dangerous. You must remember every variable that point to specific cell.